# Even though I set actions on wall post, they do not show up in graph api explorer or in FB UI

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action

I am trying play with actions that I can set on wall post with following ruby on rails code. But when I see those wall posts, these actions do not show up there. they also do not show up in graph api explorer. I am following the wall post graph api documentation but may be missing something here.

```
   actionArray = Array.new
   actionArray << {"name" => "custom1", "link" => myUrl}
   actionArray << {"name" => "custom2", "link" => myUrl}

   postId = @graph.put_wall_post("some text", {"name" => "some text",
                                               "link" => myUrl,
                                               "caption" => "caption",
                                               "description" => "description",
                                               "picture" => pictureUrl,
                                               "actions" => actionArray})
```

thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Can you send a link to the documentation you are reading, and maybe a screenshot or link to a different app's wall post that DOES contain the actions?
I am asking because I suspect that you are working off of outdated information, but I can't be sure unless I understand better what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: documentation on post api. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: This page has a table that talks about actions field. 

actions - 


A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking, and an optional app-specified action)
 
- 
Requires access_token
 

array of objects containing the name and link

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create multiple custom action links.
This document: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ describes what data you will see when you READ a post's `actions` array. For most posts created by an application (through methods like Stream.Publish, or through the Feed Dialog), you'll see three actions: Like, Comment, and a custom action defined by the application (this third one is optional, so it's not always there). However this only describes how to READ those three objects.

When CREATING a post, you can only specify ONE custom action link - the other two (like and comment) are automatically created and cannot be customized.
If you are creating posts via the Feed Dialog, read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

> actions
>   A JSON array containing a single object describing the action link which will appear next to the "Comment" and "Like" link under posts. The contained object must have the keys name and link.

So, while the "actions" parameter that you pass must be formatted like a JSON array, it can only have a single object. It ends up looking something like this:

```
actions=[{"link":"http://apps.facebook.com/myAppUrl","name":"This is Link Text"}]
```

Try doing it this way (with only one object in your Actions array) and see if it works - if not, it may be that the SDK you are using does not support the Action Link.

Comment: I tried passing only one element in an array for actions as well as just passing the name-link pair for actions. In both cases the result was same. No custom action showed up in FB page or graph api explorer. I am using server side koala graph api library for Ruby on Rails.

Comment: It may be that creating Action Links is only possible when using the Feed Dialog, although this seems like it would be a strange limitation.